# how to implement sub menus in Drawer Navigation in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

When user press on parent item listed in drawer, (if it have child items) then there child items expand and when user press on child items it navigate to the screens.

Comment: Reference: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-nested-drawer-menu-with-react-native-a1c2fdcab6c9/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.